# How does this book (Financial Theory w/ Python) arrive at the solution at the bottom?

Tags: finance, statistical-finance

I am trying to work through understanding this but I do not know how they got to the solution at the bottom (b*). Any help?

[image: image description]

Answer (score 2):

Just algebra.  Plug their $s^*$ into the first of the 2 equations $b\cdot B_1...$ then move things around so that $b$ is alone on the left hand side.

Like so:
$$b \cdot B_1 + \Big( {{C^u_1-C^d_1}\over{S^u_1-S^d_1}} \Big) S^u_1 = C^u_1,$$
then
$$b \cdot B_1 = C^u_1 - \Big( {{C^u_1-C^d_1}\over{S^u_1-S^d_1}} \Big) S^u_1,$$
then
$$b \cdot B_1 = C^u_1 \Big( {{S^u_1-S^d_1}\over{S^u_1-S^d_1}} \Big)  - \Big( {{C^u_1-C^d_1}\over{S^u_1-S^d_1}} \Big) S^u_1,$$
then
$$b \cdot B_1 = {{C^d_1 S^u_1-C^u_1 S^d_1}\over{S^u_1-S^d_1}}$$
Etc.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. When I try to move them around I don't get the answer at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!